# コントローラごとのディレクトリにindex.phpを配置したい

Tags: php, fuelphp

現在fuelphpを利用してサイトを運営しております。　
諸事情により、public直下にindex.phpを配置することができず、
サブフォルダにindex.phpを配置して運営しております。

public_html
　　|＿＿＿＿inquiry
　　　　　　　｜__________　index.php
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　.htaccess

この状態で更に別フォルダにプログラムを配置しようと思い
同じようにサブフォルダ内にindex.phpを設定したのですが

public_html
　　|＿＿＿＿function
　　　　　　　｜__________　index.php
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　.htaccess

デフォルトコントローラーをroutes.phpにてindexと
指定しており、http://example/inquiry　でアクセスが
あった場合は問題ないのですが、[http://example/functionで](http://example/function%E3%81%A7)
アクセスするとhttp://example/inquiryの画面に遷移してしまいます。

http://example/function/function　というurlでのアクセスであれば、
意図したコントローラーに遷移するのですが、url的に見た目が
よくない状態になっております。
こういった場合にどのように対処するかご存じであればご教示ください。

Answer (score 1):

routes.phpにどのような定義をされているかが分からないため確認になりますが、

http://example/inquiry にアクセス(実ファイルは public_html/inquiry/index.php)すると、
/fuel/app/classes/controller/index.phpのaction_indexメソッド が実行され、

http://example/function にアクセス(実ファイルは public_html/function/index.php)すると、
/fuel/app/classes/controller/function.phpのaction_indexメソッドが実行されるようにしたいのでしょうか？

/fuel/app/classes/contoroller/ 配下のコントローラで分けるのであれば、フロントコントローラで区別する必要はないと思いますが、何らかの理由でフロントコントローラを分ける必要があるのでば、フロントコントローラ毎のルーティングを定義する必要があります。
以下のサイトが参考になるかと思います。

FuelPHP リソースを共通化して複数サイトを構築する
http://qiita.com/yugokitajima/items/b3dc6b145fc933f53677

強引ですが、routes.phpに
'function' => 'function/index',
と定義する方法もありますが、inquiry側にも影響を与えてしまいます。

Comment: ご返答いただきありがとうございます。  
教示頂いた参考サイトの内容をヒントにやってみたいと思います。